# Realm Configuration - Change Filename

Tags: android, realm

We've been using the app name as the name set in the realm configuration, which has worked fine for the past year.

Now... the powers that be want to change the app name and it occurred to me that a better idea would be to change the name to the package name so I don't have to worry about this in the future.

My question:

What do I have to do in the realm migration to change the filename of the actual database?  I've done some searching but can only find info on changing table names

Answer (score 1):

The Realm is just a normal file on disk, so use normal Java API's to change the name and then create a new configuration for it. Warning: Don't do this while the Realm is open and I haven't actually tested it. But hopefully, you get the idea :)

```
File oldRealm = new File(getContextDir(), "default.realm");
if (oldRealm.exists()) {
  oldRealm.renameTo("new_name.realm");
}

RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
    .name("new_name.realm")
    .build();
```